# no error messages in VSCode LaTex Worksop but latex won't compile my file

Tags: biblatex, biber, vscode

There are no errors in my code as far as I know but my code won't compile in vscode LaTex Workshop. I only get a bunch of warnings after a very cryptic `Recipe terminated with error. Retry building the project.`

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{adlakha2006solving,
    author    = {Adlakha, Veena and Kowalski, Krzysztof and Lev, Benjamin},
    journal   = {International journal of management Science and Engineering management},
    title     = {Solving transportation problems with mixed constraints},
    year      = {2006},
    number    = {1},
    pages     = {47--52},
    volume    = {1},
    publisher = {Taylor \& Francis Group},
    }

    @Article{ahmed2014effective,
    author  = {Ahmed, Mollah Mesbahuddin and Tanvir, Abu Sadat Muhammad and Sultana, Shirin and Mahmud, Sultan and Uddin, Md Sharif},
    journal = {Annals of Pure and Applied Mathematics},
    title   = {An effective modification to solve transportation problems: a cost minimization approach},
    year    = {2014},
    number  = {2},
    pages   = {199--206},
    volume  = {6},
    }

    @InProceedings{alder2015chinese,
    author       = {Alder, Simon and others},
    booktitle    = {2015 Meeting Papers},
    title        = {Chinese roads in India: The effect of transport infrastructure on economic development},
    year         = {2015},
    organization = {Society for Economic Dynamics},
    volume       = {1447},
    }

    @Misc{Amponsah2009,
    author = {Amponsah, S K},
    title  = {{O}ptimization techniques lecture notes, {D}epartment of {M}athematics},
    year   = {2009},
    }

    @Article{anupindi1999centralization,
    author    = {Anupindi, Ravi and Bassok, Yehuda},
    journal   = {Management science},
    title     = {Centralization of stocks: Retailers vs. manufacturer},
    year      = {1999},
    number    = {2},
    pages     = {178--191},
    volume    = {45},
    publisher = {INFORMS},
    }

    @Article{axsater2013distribution,
    author    = {Axs{\"a}ter, Sven and Howard, Christian and Marklund, Johan},
    journal   = {Iie Transactions},
    title     = {A distribution inventory model with transshipments from a support warehouse},
    year      = {2013},
    number    = {3},
    pages     = {309--322},
    volume    = {45},
    publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
    }

    @Book{bressler1970markets,
    author    = {Bressler, Raymond George and King, Richard Adams and others},
    publisher = {Wiley New York},
    title     = {Markets, prices, and interregional trade},
    year      = {1970},
    volume    = {8},
    }

    @InProceedings{chartniyom2007multi,
    author       = {Chartniyom, Siradej and Lee, MK and Luong, L and Marian, R},
    booktitle    = {2007 IEEE International Conference on Industrial Engineering and Engineering Management},
    title        = {Multi-location inventory system with lateral transshipments and emergency orders},
    year         = {2007},
    organization = {IEEE},
    pages        = {1594--1598},
    }

    @Article{Coyac2015,
    author = {Coyac, C G G A},
    title  = {Analysis and improvement of transshipment operations in jer{\'o}nimo martins},
    year   = {2015},
    }

    @PhdThesis{cudjoe2015transshipment,
    author = {Cudjoe, Manasseh},
    title  = {Transshipment Problem Of A Non-Alcoholic Beverage Industry: Case Study Of Coca Cola Bottling Company, Ghana},
    year   = {2015},
    }

    @Article{frimpong2015transportation,
    author    = {Frimpong, Frank Osei and Asare, Akwasi Poku},
    journal   = {Transportation},
    title     = {Transportation Problem for a Beverage Firm in Kumasi, Ghana},
    year      = {2015},
    number    = {2},
    volume    = {5},
    publisher = {Citeseer},
    }

    @Article{gao2013modified,
    author    = {Gao, Cai and Wei, Daijun and Hu, Yong and Mahadevan, Sankaran and Deng, Yong},
    journal   = {Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications},
    title     = {A modified evidential methodology of identifying influential nodes in weighted networks},
    year      = {2013},
    number    = {21},
    pages     = {5490--5500},
    volume    = {392},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Article{gao2014biologically,
    author  = {Gao, Cai and Yan, Chao and Wei, Daijun and Hu, Yong and Mahadevan, Sankaran and Deng, Yong},
    journal = {arXiv preprint arXiv:1401.2181},
    title   = {A biologically inspired model for transshipment problem},
    year    = {2014},
    }

    @Article{khurana2015variants,
    author    = {Khurana, Archana},
    journal   = {European Transport Research Review},
    title     = {Variants of transshipment problem},
    year      = {2015},
    number    = {2},
    pages     = {1--19},
    volume    = {7},
    publisher = {SpringerOpen},
    }

    @Article{liao2014optimal,
    author    = {Liao, Yi and Shen, Wenjing and Hu, Xinxin and Yang, Shilei},
    journal   = {Omega},
    title     = {Optimal responses to stockouts: Lateral transshipment versus emergency order policies},
    year      = {2014},
    pages     = {79--92},
    volume    = {49},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Article{njoh2008implications,
    author    = {Njoh, Ambe J},
    journal   = {The Review of Black Political Economy},
    title     = {Implications of Africa's transportation systems for development in the era of globalization},
    year      = {2008},
    number    = {4},
    pages     = {147--162},
    volume    = {35},
    publisher = {SAGE Publications Sage CA: Los Angeles, CA},
    }

    @Article{ozdemir2006multi,
    author    = {{\"O}zdemir, Deniz and Y{\"u}cesan, Enver and Herer, Yale T},
    journal   = {European Journal of Operational Research},
    title     = {Multi-location transshipment problem with capacitated transportation},
    year      = {2006},
    number    = {1},
    pages     = {602--621},
    volume    = {175},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Article{paterson2011inventory,
    author    = {Paterson, Colin and Kiesm{\"u}ller, Gudrun and Teunter, Ruud and Glazebrook, Kevin},
    journal   = {European Journal of Operational Research},
    title     = {Inventory models with lateral transshipments: A review},
    year      = {2011},
    number    = {2},
    pages     = {125--136},
    volume    = {210},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Article{paterson2012enhanced,
    author    = {Paterson, Colin and Teunter, Ruud and Glazebrook, Kevin},
    journal   = {European Journal of Operational Research},
    title     = {Enhanced lateral transshipments in a multi-location inventory system},
    year      = {2012},
    number    = {2},
    pages     = {317--327},
    volume    = {221},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Article{reeb1998using,
    author = {Reeb, James Edmund and Leavengood, Scott A and others},
    title  = {Using the simplex method to solve linear programming maximization problems},
    year   = {1998},
    }

    @Article{singh2017new,
    author  = {Singh, Rashmi and Saxena, Vipin},
    journal = {International journal of advanced research in computer science},
    title   = {A New Data Transfer Approach Through Fuzzy Vogel's Approximation Method.},
    year    = {2017},
    number  = {3},
    volume  = {8},
    }

    @Article{singh2015note,
    author  = {Singh, Sarbjit},
    journal = {Universal Journal of Industrial and Business Management},
    title   = {Note on transportation problem with new method for resolution of degeneracy},
    year    = {2015},
    number  = {1},
    pages   = {26--36},
    volume  = {3},
    }

    @Article{slater1997architects,
    author  = {Slater, Rodney E},
    journal = {Public Roads},
    title   = {Architects of Change: Creating America's 21st Century Intermodal Transportation System},
    year    = {1997},
    number  = {3},
    volume  = {60},
    }

    @Article{tagaras2001periodic,
    author    = {Tagaras, George and Vlachos, Dimitrios},
    journal   = {Management Science},
    title     = {A periodic review inventory system with emergency replenishments},
    year      = {2001},
    number    = {3},
    pages     = {415--429},
    volume    = {47},
    publisher = {INFORMS},
    }

    @Article{van2009optimal,
    author    = {Van Wijk, ACC and Adan, IJBF and van Houtum, Geert-Jan},
    journal   = {Eurandom report, Eindhoven University of Technology},
    title     = {Optimal lateral transshipment policy for a two location inventory problem},
    year      = {2009},
    publisher = {Citeseer},
    }

    @Article{wee2005optimal,
    author    = {Wee, Kwan Eng and Dada, Maqbool},
    journal   = {Management Science},
    title     = {Optimal policies for transshipping inventory in a retail network},
    year      = {2005},
    number    = {10},
    pages     = {1519--1533},
    volume    = {51},
    publisher = {INFORMS},
    }

    @Article{zou2010two,
    author    = {Zou, Li and Dresner, Martin and Windle, Robert},
    journal   = {International Journal of Production Economics},
    title     = {A two-location inventory model with transshipments in a competitive environment},
    year      = {2010},
    number    = {2},
    pages     = {235--250},
    volume    = {125},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    }

    @Online{Tanko2013,
    author = {Bagbara Tanko},
    date   = {2013-09-18},
    note   = {Accessed: 01.2.2018},
    title  = {The role and impact of road infrastructure on poverty reduction},
    url    = {https://www.ghanaweb.com/GhanaHomePage/features/The-role-and-impact-of-road-infrastructure-on-poverty-reduction-286231},
    }

    @InProceedings{UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009,
    author      = {{United Nations. Economic Commission for Africa} and {United Nations. Economic and Social Council}},
    title       = {The transport situaiton in {A}frica},
    publisher   = {UN. ECA},
    date        = {2009},
    eventdate   = {2009-10-13/2009-10-15},
    eventtitle  = {UN. ECA committee on Trade, Regional Cooperation and Integration (6th Session: 2009, Oct. 13-15: Addis Ababa, Ethiopia)},
    location    = {Addis Ababa, Ethiopia},
    shortauthor = {UNECA and UNESC},
    url         = {http://hdl.handle.net/10855/3252},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction}
    We cite the article \textcite{UniEconomicSocialCouncil2009}. And this is also for good measure\textcite{zou2010two}.

    % BACK MATTER
    \clearpage
    \printbibliography[title=References]
    \nocite{*}


\end{document}
```

And here is my LaTex Recipe

```
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ biblatex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my settings. You missed  `"env": {}`
Also, next time post `Latex Compiler Log`

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
 {
      "name": "pdflatex",
      "command": "pdflatex",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    },
 {
      "name": "biber",
      "command": "biber",
      "args": ["%DOCFILE%"],
      "env": {}
    },
],

// LaTeX RECIPES
  "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
 {
      "name": "pdflatex ➞ biber ➞ pdflatex × 2",
      "tools": ["pdflatex", "biber", "pdflatex", "pdflatex"]
    },
],
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask what the importance of the ```env: {}``` bit is? It used to work without it.

Comment: "The `env` entry is a dictionary. " see more here> <https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile#latex-recipes>